# /usr/include/stdio.h:140: parse error before `__gnuc_va_list'

Tags: compiling, gcc, sco

I keep getting this error, when trying to compile my `C` program in SCO (using `gcc`).

I have had a look on Google, and found this other forum: [Linux Questions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/stdio-h-parse-error-before-__gnuc_va_list-141854/), and that guy had the exact same issue as I am getting. So I tried his solution, which is adding a line at the top of the `program.c` file:

```
#include "err.h"
```

I tried compiling again, and now I get one line back:

```
program.c:5: err.h: No such file or directory
```

- Do I need to add / install to get that file?
- Where would this file be in my file-system?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

`vi hello.c`:

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
```

`gcc -v hello.c`:

```
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/specs
gcc version 2.95.2 19991024 (release)
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/cpp -lang-c -v -D__GNUC__=2 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=95 -Asystem(svr3) -Acpu(i386) -Amachine(i386) -Di386 -D__i386 -D__i386__ -D__i386 -D__unix -D_SCO_DS=1 -D_M_I386 -D_M_XENIX -D_M_UNIX -D_STRICT_NAMES -D_SCO_XPG_VERS=4 -D_M_I86 -D_M_I86SM -D_M_INTERNAT -D_M_SDATA -D_M_STEXT -D_M_BITFIELDS -D_M_SYS5 -D_M_SYSV -D_M_SYSIII -D_M_WORDSWAP -Dunix -DM_I386 -DM_UNIX -DM_XENIX -D_SCO_ELF -D_SCO_C_DIALECT=1 hello.c /usr/tmp/cc1HX7yg.i
GNU CPP version 2.95.2 19991024 (release) (i386, SCO OpenServer 5 Syntax)
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/../../../../i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/include
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
The following default directories have been omitted from the search path:
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/../../../../include/g++-3
End of omitted list.
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/cc1 /usr/tmp/cc1HX7yg.i -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -version -o /usr/tmp/cc4HAEHq.s
GNU C version 2.95.2 19991024 (release) (i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5) compiled by GNU C version  2.95.2 19991024 (release).
In file included from hello.c:3:
 /usr/include/stdio.h:140: parse error before `__gnuc_va_list'
 /usr/include/stdio.h:140: parse error before `__gnuc_va_list'
 /usr/include/stdio.h:140: parse error before `__gnuc_va_list'
```

Comment: From what I remember of your past questions, you still haven't installed gcc properly. Gcc needs its own copy of system headers, it looks like it isn't getting them.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, I remember now too. But I think I got it installed, as when I type `gcc` it shows: `gcc: No input files`. So I think it is installed now.

Comment: This shows that you have the binary in the right place, but not that you have the other parts. In particular, you probably don't have the right headers in the right place. To help you with this, we'd need to know exactly how you installed the compiler (as in, a copy-paste of all the commands you typed).

Comment: Right @Gilles, I can't exactly remember, but I found out with my other questions. I used WinSCP (SSH) to copy a .tar.gz file to my `/u/test/installgnu/gcc/` folder. I then went into the terminal, using `PuTTY`, and un-tarred the file. `tar xzvf gcc-2.95.2pl1-dist.tar.gz` - I seriously can't remember if I used the `2.95.2pl1-dist...` or the 12.95.2pl1-VOLS.tar`. I typed `gcc -v` and got this back: `/usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/specs
gcc version 2.95.2 19991024 (release)`. Does that help?

Comment: Then using `scoadmin software` I installed gcc.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the contents of `program.c`, and the output of `gcc -v program.c`. (Remove the line with `err.h`.)

Comment: I'm sorry @Gilles, My company won't allow me to add the contents of the `.c` file. I am trying to reinstall the gcc compiler now. I uninstalled the other one, in case it might've been corrupt, but now I tried to `tar xvzf gcc-2.95.2pl1-dist.tar.gz`, and it won't work .... great! (no it's not great)

Comment: Do you get the same error with a simple "hello world" test program?

Comment: Yes, I have just made a simple `Hello World!` program, and has generated the same errors. I will add to my question what the contents is of the `hello.c` file and the `gcc -v hello.c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `C/C++` you have `#include ""` and `#include <>` , When you use `""` It means you introduce your header file to compiler, So you need to `-I` in compile time such as:

```
gcc -I. -I../Includes program.c
```

`-I` get an argument as path of your includes files, When you use `stdio` or `stdlib`, they are default installed in `gcc` path and introduced to your `gcc`.

Comment: Thank you for that, I did that, and this is what is now returned (better): `bash-3.1$ gcc -I. -I../opt/K/SKUNK99/Gcc/2.95.2pl1/usr/local/include/g++-3/ program.c
program.c:19: vcl.h: No such file or directory
program.c:22: windows.h: No such file or directory
program.c:69: stdafx.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: along with above path, add `-I/usr/include`

Comment: So should the path say: `gcc -I. -I/opt/K/SKUNK99/...`? Sorry, I'm just confused.

Comment: I don't know SCO, but gcc has a default path When you run `gcc -v`  You can find out its default path.enjoy it.